# HikariCP configuration not working in my app developed in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have an application developed in Springboot and I am in need to use Connection Pool settings as connections are getting exhausted while running a load test. I am relying on SpringBoot auto configuration to set the "datasource". Application is working fine when tested in my local workspace in IntelliJ but the same is not working when deployed in Kubernetes cluster. My spring boot version in 2.6.6 and using JDK11.

I have read that based on "spring.datasource.url" springBoot identifies the driver class name, but in my case it is not happening

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties looks like below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@......
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

#connection pool configuration
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=SVMConnectionPool
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=60
```

Error that I see in the logs

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696439652Z      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696442966Z      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696445978Z      ... 121 more
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696449043Z  Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:252)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:193)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696457775Z      at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696460846Z      at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696464391Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696467454Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696470269Z      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-07-14T05:34:41.696473242Z      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

Comment: Looks like the oracle driver isn't part of yuour dependencies. Also you shouldn't need to specify a version for your starter dependencies (assuming you have the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your `<parent>`).

Comment: oracle driver is also part of the dependency, updated the earlier post

Comment: How are you constructing the jar? If you are using the proper way it should be part of your fatjar. Also are you using the same properties for your other deployment? Looks like either the JDBC isn't there **or** you are using different URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Spring source code where the exception is thrown. It will be thrown only if there is **NO** property `driver-class-name`. Your code shows however that it is present in `application.properties`.

The only reasonable explanation is that the above property file is either missing in the application JAR or not on the classpath.

Based on: [DataSourceProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java)

Comment: I have used exactly same DB connection string that works in my local workspace. Just to be in sync with codebase